# How to plot a superimposed bar chart using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I want to plot a bar chart or a histogram using matplotlib. I don't want a stacked bar plot, but a superimposed barplot of two lists of data, for instance I have the following two lists of data with me:

Some code to begin with :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal, uniform

highPower   = [1184.53,1523.48,1521.05,1517.88,1519.88,1414.98,1419.34,
              1415.13,1182.70,1165.17]
lowPower    = [1000.95,1233.37, 1198.97,1198.01,1214.29,1130.86,1138.70,
               1104.12,1012.95,1000.36]

plt.hist(highPower, bins=10, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True,
         color='b', label='Max Power in mW')
plt.hist(lowPower, bins=10, histtype='stepfilled', normed=True,
         color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Min Power in mW')
```

I want to plot these two lists against the number of values in the two lists such that I am able to see the variation per reading.

Comment: yes I am posting it in the edit of the question

Comment: take a look at `numpy.cumsum()` and `pyplot.hist()`...

Comment: pyplot.hist() how do I use that?

Comment: @Ffisegydd any help you can offer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can produce a superimposed bar chart using [`plt.bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) with the `alpha` keyword as shown below.

The `alpha` controls the transparency of the bar.

**N.B.** when you have two overlapping bars, one with an alpha < 1, you will get a mixture of colours. As such the bar will appear purple even though the legend shows it as a light red. To alleviate this I have modified the width of one of the bars, this way even if your powers should change you will still be able to see both bars.

[`plt.xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) can be used to set the location and format of the x-ticks in your graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

width = 0.8

highPower   = [1184.53,1523.48,1521.05,1517.88,1519.88,1414.98,
               1419.34,1415.13,1182.70,1165.17]
lowPower    = [1000.95,1233.37, 1198.97,1198.01,1214.29,1130.86,
               1138.70,1104.12,1012.95,1000.36]

indices = np.arange(len(highPower))

plt.bar(indices, highPower, width=width, 
        color='b', label='Max Power in mW')
plt.bar([i+0.25*width for i in indices], lowPower, 
        width=0.5*width, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Min Power in mW')

plt.xticks(indices+width/2., 
           ['T{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(highPower))] )

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: There is no values in the list that exceeds 2000, then how does this bar chart show a value greater than 2000 and the labels on the x-axis have to be [1,2,3,4,.....,10] but it shows in the increments of 2

Comment: I don't want them stacked on top of each other rather they should be superimposing each other that is lower value should occupy some region of the bar with a higher value

Comment: Great, this works, thankyou for the explanation too :) but how do I modify the ticks on the x axis to be T1,T2,T3 and so on

Comment: I have added an example of how to set the x-ticks to be "T1", "T2", etc. In the future however I would advise that you either explain your question fully at the beginning (not add more sub-questions on as you go) or simply ask a new question for your extended questions.

Comment: when I run this code, the red bars show on the right side of the blue bar, instead of the middle. Can you update the code?

Comment: How to get the legend colors to match with the actual colors?

Answer (score 6):

Building on @Ffisegydd's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293276/623735), if your data is in a Pandas DataFrame, this should work nicely:

```
def overlapped_bar(df, show=False, width=0.9, alpha=.5,
                   title='', xlabel='', ylabel='', **plot_kwargs):
    """Like a stacked bar chart except bars on top of each other with transparency"""
    xlabel = xlabel or df.index.name
    N = len(df)
    M = len(df.columns)
    indices = np.arange(N)
    colors = ['steelblue', 'firebrick', 'darksage', 'goldenrod', 'gray'] * int(M / 5. + 1)
    for i, label, color in zip(range(M), df.columns, colors):
        kwargs = plot_kwargs
        kwargs.update({'color': color, 'label': label})
        plt.bar(indices, df[label], width=width, alpha=alpha if i else 1, **kwargs)
        plt.xticks(indices + .5 * width,
                   ['{}'.format(idx) for idx in df.index.values])
    plt.legend()
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if show:
        plt.show()
    return plt.gcf()
```

And then in a python command line:

```
low = [1000.95, 1233.37, 1198.97, 1198.01, 1214.29, 1130.86, 1138.70, 1104.12, 1012.95, 1000.36]
high = [1184.53, 1523.48, 1521.05, 1517.88, 1519.88, 1414.98, 1419.34, 1415.13, 1182.70, 1165.17]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix([high, low]).T, columns=['High', 'Low'],
                  index=pd.Index(['T%s' %i for i in range(len(high))],
                  name='Index'))
overlapped_bar(df, show=False)
```

[image: overlapped bar chart in matplotlib]

Comment: Trying this code and it displays the bar chart twice, Can the code be edited so it only displays the graph once?

Comment: How would you also change the fig size for this graph? I cannot seem to change it doing it the standard way

Comment: @CathalBrady are you using Spider? What is your python environment? This code will only work in a full python environment with matplotlib and its backend configured correctly for your OS or environment. You'll have to do something slightly different in a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Somehow there's no darksage in my environnement.
I also tried to modify it to barh because I think vertical bars look better for my data, but my attempts break the index 

Answer (score 6):

It is actually simpler than the answers all over the internet make it appear.

```
a = range(1,10)
b = range(4,13)
ind = np.arange(len(a))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x=ind, height=a, width=0.35,align='center')
ax.bar(x=ind, height=b, width=0.35/3,  align='center')

plt.xticks(ind, a)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]